# Image in Dropdown Div (onclick) won't activate the dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, onclick

So we have a simple dropdown, but when you click the image, it doesn't activate the dropdown.

Since we've done this in Shopify there are a few code segments that make it difficult to write out. So I've just recreated in CodePen. As you can see in the example, clicking on the image does not activate the dropdown.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRLbYw

HTML

```
<div class="dropdownprod">
              <div onclick="dropDowntown()" class="dropbtn">
                <span class="dropdowncheese">Styles</span>PRODUCT TITLE<img class="dropimg2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Small_rhombihexahedron.png" style="height:45px;"></div>
              <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
               THE DROPDOWN CONTENT GOES HERE
              </div>
             </div>
```

JS

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function dropDowntown() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if you click on the image, and inspect source, the code part is going purple. It's just not changing. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/7uhno3q0/ or are you expecting something different?

Comment: It doesn't work for me on the jsfiddle either. Note, I'm not talking about clicking the text _Product Title_. I'm wondering why the **dropdown doesn't activate when clicking the image**. That doesn't work for me on both exampes, in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of your `window.onclick` function to close the dropdown.  When you click the image or span, `dropDowntown()` fires adding the class, then `window.onclick()` fires instantly removing it.  Add the span and image to your if statement so they do not trigger the closing script.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was indeed the problem. Sorry, I'm still learning this stuff haha. Probably a pretty simple mistake.